# How to compare Web SQL data to fetched json and then delete certain objects if ID's match

Tags: sql, ajax, json, cordova, web

I'm reaching out to those who have some experience with cordova web sql. If you can solve this problem you will get a thank you when this project becomes open source through github. I'm fetching json from wordpress and I'm rendering all the posts in a phonegap cordova ios app. I have already made a function in index.js called addRead that stores the posts id in the local web sql database. This part is figured out but when I am doing the ajax request (with jquery) I can render all the posts but I want to filter out the posts that have been read, the ones that are in my table called readposts.

To give you a perspective, this is the addRead function and my table:

```
createTable: function () {
        app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS readposts(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, postid INTEGER, added_on TEXT)", [],
                app.onSuccess, app.onError);
        });
    },    

addRead: function (postid) {
        app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var ts = new Date().toUTCString();
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO readposts(postid, added_on) VALUES (?,?)", [postid, ts], app.onSuccess, app.onError);
        });
    }
```

I'm fetching the json from here (you don't have to look through everything, just find out where the posts and the ids are): **http://eter.rudbeck.info/category/sjalvstudier/?json=1&count=10&apikey=ErtYnDsKATCzmuf6**

Inside the ajax request success function I'm looping through the readposts table and inside this loop going through the fetched json. Inside an if statement I am comparing the postid inside the table with the id from the fetched json. If they match I want to delete that post from the json.

My code seem logical to me and all the loops work but the program ignores my if statement and still renders all the posts even though the table's postid:s matched with the id:s from the fetched json. This is what it looks like inside the success function in the ajax get request (I've commented out the render code because it is not relevant):

```
success: function(data){
               app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM readposts ORDER BY ID DESC", [], function (tx, rs) {
                        var row;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) { // loop through web sql db
                            row = rs.rows.item(i);
                            $.each(data.posts, function(index, obj) { // loop through fetched json       
                                if(parseInt(row.postid) == parseInt(obj.id)) // make sure both values are integers {
                                    delete obj;
                                }
                            });        
                        }
                    }, app.onError);
               });

               // This is the render code, ignore it
               /*
               var source   = $("#blog-template").html();
               var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
               var blogData = template(data);
               $('#blog-data').html(blogData);
               $('#blog-data').trigger('create');
               dfd.resolve(data);
               $(".nav1 li a").removeClass('active-menu');       
               $('#btn-senaste').addClass("active-menu"); 
               $('#recommended-data').html('<p></p>'); 
               */
           },
```

Both of the loops work but the if statement where I try ro delete the posts is ignored. I believe that is the piece of code that needs to be fixed.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your "if" statement may be evaluating to true, but the delete statement is not having an effect.
You can't delete the value object passed by jQuery's $.each() function; you need to delete it in the context of its parent object - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpa99c/pd0rk22d/)

So try something like this:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(index, obj) { // loop through fetched json       
    if(parseInt(row.postid) == parseInt(obj.id)) // make sure both values are integers {
        delete data.posts[index];
    }
});
```

I'd recommend using a step-through debugger to place a breakpoint on the line you suspect; that way you can inspect the values of the variables and determine what's going on. 
Depending what platform you're testing on, if it's Android 4.4+ you can use [Chrome remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), iOS 6+ then [Safari remote debugging](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/), or Ripple emulator then plain old Chrome Dev tools.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this did not work. I found out that the if statement goes off by using alerts throughout the function. I don't think I can use safaris debugger since I think the web sql database only works with ondeviceready. Look at the code in my next comment:

Comment: You can definitely use Safari's debugger to debug a cordova app with a WebSQL database - I've done it many times. You can step through the JS, you just can't inspect the DB directly like you can with Chrome. Without seeing your entire source code, it hard to see where the problem lies. If the "if" statement is evaluating to true and the delete is still not working, perhaps the scope of the `data.posts` is the problem. try dumping it to the console after the delete, i.e. `console.dir(data.posts)`

Comment: This explains how to setup iOS for remote debugging with safari: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Answer (score 0):

Again, I used alerts and the alert inside the if statement went off. My next step is to try to render the json as a string inside the app and see if the choosen posts have been deleted. If this works then there must be something wrong with the rendering of the posts. Perhaps everything renders before the json is manipulated.

```
app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM readposts ORDER BY ID DESC", [], function (tx, rs) {
                        var row;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) { // loop through web sql db
                            row = rs.rows.item(i);
                            alert("db postid: "+row.postid);
                            $.each(data.posts, function(index, obj) { // loop through fetched json       
                                alert("index: "+index+", obj.id: "+obj.id);
                                if(parseInt(row.postid) === parseInt(obj.id)) {
                                    alert("match! delete postid="+row.postid+",obj,id"+obj.id );
                                    delete data.posts[index];
                                }
                            });        
                        }
                    }, app.onError);
               });
```